# Flex 4, AdvancedDataGrid: initial column width

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, column-width

I got a problem with the widths of the advanceddatagrid-columns.
First of all, my layout is a HDividedBox, on the left there is the navigation, on the right there is a module, containing the advanceddatagrid.

left Side: navigation

right side: module (e.g. advanceddatagrid)

Most of the columns got a fixed width, some a minWidth. Now, initially the widths of the columns are correct.

So the problem is, whenever I load a new module and later reload the advanceddatagrid, the initial width of the columns is way different, although I change nothing in the process of loading the module. Neither the fixed widths nor the minWidths are initially correct.
I recently saw there is a solution for wrong widths of colums, it looks like that:

```
var oldPolicy:String = advanceddatagrid.myScrollPolicy;
advanceddatagrid.myScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON;

for(var i:int = 0; i < advanceddatagrid.columns.length; i++) {
    var column:AdvancedDataGridColumn = advanceddatagrid.columns[i] as AdvancedDataGridColumn;
    advanceddatagrid.column.width = column.width;
}
advanceddatagrid.validateNow();             
advanceddatagrid.myScrollPolicy = oldPolicy;                
advanceddatagrid.validateNow();
```

On the whole this is just a temporary change of the ScrollPolicy, re-setting the column-widths and then changing back. But still, it doenst work.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: inside your `for` loop, this line looks suspicious: `advanceddatagrid.column.width = advanceddatagrid.column.width;`. Shouldn't it be using the column variable from the line above?

Comment: oh you're right. i just misspelled it here. in my original script it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some relevant references that might help (the first one worked for me):

http://userflex.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/force-resize-datagrid/

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4285461

To summarize the first post (credit goes to Nick Schneble):

```
public function resizeColumns () : void
{
    grid.validateNow ();
    // forces the columns to size themselves properly
    for each (var column : AdvancedDataGridColumn in grid.columns)
    {
        column.width = column.width;
    } 
}
```

It may seem a bit ridiculous, but if you execute this method whenever the underlying data in your data grid changes, you’ll have beautifully laid out columns.